# Create a table row in Mat Table independent of table headers?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to have a row at the top of the table (similar to the mat-footer) but at the top of all data elements.  It seems like you cannot create table rows without them fitting into the defined mat-header-cells.  Is it possible to add a tr to the top of a mat-table that is independent of the headers defined in the table?

Comment: you can create a row that have single column that spans over other columns.

Comment: If I try to create a row that has the full width of the table, it pushes all of the other accurately sized columns over to the right.

Comment: but you have to have 2 <tr> tag with different mat-columns set each and *ngIf between them so single column row is rendered once and rest of the rows are the other <tr>. This is the exact same trick as making expandable rows with mat-table